# KeystoneJS dependsOn not saving its new value when disappear

Tags: keystonejs

```
User.add({
    name: { type: Types.Name, required: true },
    userid: { type: Types.Text, initial: true, required: true },
    exceed_login_attempt: { 
        type: Types.Boolean,
        default: false, 
        label: 'Exceeded Invalid Login Attempts',
        dependsOn: { exceed_login_attempt: true }
    }
});
```

I have here a checkbox input field `exceed_login_attempt` I want this to be display in AdminUI if the value is `true` (checked). If I unchecked that the value is `false` and the checkbox will disappear - this is fine.

But when I save it the checkbox value which is `false` is not save. After rendering the page the value is still `true`, which means it displays again the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

On KeystoneJS [database documentation](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-conditional) it is mentioned that:

> To improve the usability of the Admin UI, it is possible to hide fields when no value is set, or depending on the value of **other fields**.

A field can depend on the value of **other fields**. But in your posted code, the `exceed_login_attempt` field, depends on its own value, which doesn't look right to me:

```
exceed_login_attempt: { 
        ...
        dependsOn: { exceed_login_attempt: true }
    }
```

---

I'm not sure, maybe you intend to use `collapse` rather than `dependsOn`:

> collapse [Boolean] Displays an + add link in the admin UI when the field has no value. Will completely hide field UI when noedit is also set to true, when the field has no value